# dynamic multidimension vector

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

Is it possible that multidimension vector work this way by creating new value into vector dynamically, not fixed array size as multidimension array does?

Such as below array where [0] will create new array ['24']['25'] more than [1]

```
[0]['22']['23']['24']['25']
[1]['22']['23']
[2]['34']
```

How do I get how many array on row[0]?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, although in flash arrays are dynamically size and vectors are fixed sized.

What you are looking for is called a ragged array - in flash this is just an array of arrays or nested Arrays.

Here is a [site that describes the concept](http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2010/01/13/multidimensional-arrays-in-as3/) - I'd recommend reading all of it, but the specific part is called "The Solution: Nested Arrays", halfway down the page: